# What happens when ability scores reach 0?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

D&D 5E does not seem to have rules for ability score damage (that I could find), although it does mention that if CON is decreased, your maximum HP is reduced.

In addition, the Shadow monster in the Monster Manual has a Strength Drain attack that deals 1d4 Strength damage. The attack says that if a character's Strength reaches 0, the character dies.

Are there any general rules for ability damage in 5th Edition?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are no general rules for ability damage, almost certainly because ability damage in 5e is *incredibly* rare.

With that said, there are some sources of ability damage, so it's worth taking a look at them. The following effects are the only sources of ability damage I can find:

- The Intellect Devourer's *Devour Intellect* ability (MM 191), which can reduce a target's Intelligence to 0. If this happens, the target is stunned until it regains a point of Intelligence.
- The Shadow's *Strength Drain* ability (MM 269), which reduces a target's Strength by 1d4. If their Strength score reaches 0, they die.

It's not much to reach a conclusion from, but it seems clear that the consequences of an ability score reaching 0 depends on what ability score it is. It may even depend on the effect that causes it; perhaps Intelligence reaching 0 from *Devour Intellect* is different to Intelligence reaching 0 from some dastardly Intelligence-reducing disease.

It's *possible*, but by no means guaranteed, that a mental ability score reaching 0 causes a creature to be stunned until it regains a point of that ability score, and a physical ability score reaching 0 causes a creature to die. Obviously, this is based on the 2 examples we currently have, so it's not exactly scientific.

With all of that said, if, in your game, someone's ability score reaches 0  for a reason other than these 2 effects, it must be an effect you've added. That being the case, it's up to you to decide what the consequences of this occurring would be.

Comment: +1. Given the overall design of monster abilities, I would bet that effects are per ability, for maximum design flexibility.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie From the sound of it you are correct. It might be one of the things they intentionally left on the [cutting room floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_room_floor) to be able to tailor the results of ability drain on each effect/spell/creature entry

Comment: The [Maurezhi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/maurezhi) Bite attack is relevant, and did not exist at the time of posting:
"If the target is a humanoid, its Charisma score is reduced by 1d4...The target dies if this reduces its Charisma to 0. It rises 24 hours later as a ghoul, unless it has been revived or its corpse has been destroyed."