# Is a mount considered an "ally" for the purpose of Pack Tactics?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, mount, mounted-combat

I suppose this applies both to NPCs and player characters.

Specifically, someone proposed the idea of a PC kobold (a playable race from *Volo's Guide to Monsters*, p. 119) as a paladin, summoning a mount, and attacking with constant advantage as a result. This made me wonder: would that actually work?

[Kobolds' Pack Tactics feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/kobold#KoboldTraits) has the following description:

> You have advantage on an attack roll against a creature if at least one of your allies is within 5 feet of the creature and the ally isn’t incapacitated.

(The [monster statblock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kobold) and its variants have an identical trait, except that it is written in third person.)

**Would a mount count as an ally for the purpose of Pack Tactics?**

Comment: Related: [Is weapon reach measured from the edge of the mount's space or the rider's?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87840/is-weapon-reach-measured-from-the-edge-of-the-mounts-space-or-the-riders)

Comment: One side note, this "constant advantage" would only work indoors (where mounted combat isn't very likely), at night, or in heavy shade like deep woods due to the Kobolds also having Sunlight Sensitivity, and that disadvantage would offset the advantage.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Yes, as long as the mount is within 5 feet

An *ally* is not clearly defined in 5e, so we can use the English definition:

> a person, group, or nation that is associated with another or others for some common cause or purpose

Ally in the case of D&D 5e is almost certainly meant to include animals since wolves get the Pack Tactics trait too so we just have to assume the mount has "a common cause or purpose"

> Find Steed
>
> [...]
>
> Your steed serves you as a mount, both in combat and out, and you have an instinctive bond with it that allows you to **fight as a seamless unit.**

(**emphasis** mine) fighting as a seamless unit certainly implies a common cause, so a found steed would have this qualification as an Ally.

Most steeds has some level of intelligence (comparable to a wolf) so it can share other goals with you too, but a found steed can have more advanced goals (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105873/at-what-point-does-a-characters-int-drop-far-enough-to-lose-sentience) on creature sentience).

**Even a normal steed should count as an ally, but a found steed has extra qualifications as an ally.**

### Is the mount within 5 feet?

There are some cases where your mount won't be within 5 feet of the enemy (such as if you are attacking a creature 5 feet above you and you are at the highest point on your mount), but typical mounted combat will place your mount within 5 feet of any creature you target in melee.

Additionally, attacking with a reach or ranged weapon would not necessarily qualify as the ally needs to be **within 5 feet of the creature you are attacking**, just make sure you keep that aspect in mind.

Comment: @Meta4ic If you have follow-up questions outside the scope of your original, we'd prefer you ask them in a new question where you can re-engage our Q&A features.

Comment: Note also that _Find Greater Steed_ explicitly includes the option of a dire wolf, which itself has Pack Tactics.  Aside from the deliciousness of the mount and its rider giving each other advantage, it is a hint that yes, it is supposed to work like this.

Answer (score 10):

## Yes, the mount would count as an ally provided it would assist you in combat.

*Would it assist you in combat?* A found (discovered; such as in the wild) or purchased mount doesn't automatically fight when you do, though they can certainly be trained for combat.

In the example of a paladin's mount (which is not a found or purchased mount), however, it is combat trained to serve as a mount in combat. Due to its increased intelligence and telepathic bond, I would rule it to be threatening squares even if you were not mounted.

Comment: Just as a clarification, there is no limitation on Pack Tactics that requires your ally to be combat trained, or even that it is actively assisting you.  Only that it is not currently incapacitated.