# Is a Sentient Weapon considered an ally for the purposes of Pack Tactics?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, racial-traits, intelligent-magic-items

Related to [This Question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121359/is-a-mount-considered-an-ally-for-the-purpose-of-pack-tactics):

A Sentient Weapon is a kind of [Sentient Magic Item](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sentient%20Magic%20Items#content), and it can communicate, perceive, and is considered an NPC controlled by the GM.

> Sentient magic items function as NPCs under the DM’s control.

Since it possesses sentience and is not simply an extension of the Player Character, does it count as an ally for the purposes of Pack Tactics? Would a Kobold with a Sentient Weapon run around attacking with advantage all the time?

Answer (score 23):

### No.

Sentient magical items are [objects](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/02/18/does-a-sentient-magic-item-count-as-a-creature/) and thus cannot take actions on their own and thus are considered an ally the same way your tunic, bow, boots or belt are considered an ally. Which is that they are not.

Thank you @Rubiksmoose for this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/655070634540576772) as well. The line of reasoning points to only creatures can be allies as it states that spell effects are also exempt. Certain spells call out that they actually create temporarily or otherwise a creature, like Simulacrum, Tiny Servant and Animate Objects.

Further evidence to support this is that Pack Tactics indicates that the ally cannot be *incapacitated* and the conditions in the PHB 291 indicate that creatures (not objects) have conditions.

I realize this evidence is a tad soft but it is what it is, and personally some of them should affect a sentient item such as Blindness. This has no bearing on combat obviously but definitely on its senses and ability to locate things based on sight. So you could (like I will) rationalize that it applies the equivalent to that condition if you want to get really, really technical.

All of the spells that I know of that apply a condition also only target creatures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76601/discussion-between-slagmoth-and-seraphswrath).